# html, javascript - open a new tab every time a form gets submitted using Post method

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I have an **html** form with a **select** field where user selects which table we'll show him/her from the **mySql** database.

```html
<form action = "tableOutput.php" method="post" name="frmTableSelect" target="_blank"> 
        <p>Select a table from the list</p>
        <select name="tableName" autofocus>
    <!-- here I load a list of tables from mySql. for simplicity let it be: -->
            <option>table 1</option>
        <option>table 2</option>
         <p><br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="knopka" value="show table"></p>
     </form>
```

Like this, when user hits the button, a new tab opens up where the selected table gets printed (I process it in "tableOutput.php") - this is fine.

But the user needs to return to the first form and select another table, that should be printed in *another* tab, whereas it gets printed in the same tab as the first one *replacing* it.
In other words, we need to be able to open many new tabs with output.

I inserted this javascript:

```html
    <script>
      knopka.onclick = function() { 
        window.open("tableOutput.php")
      };
    </script>
```

Now a tab gets open every time one hits the button, but the POST method in "tableOutput.php" does not work anymore, so we get an error while processing the query.

If I write

```html
<script>
  knopka.submit = function() {   
    alert('inside javascript'); 
    window.open("tableOutput.php")
  };
</script>
```

nothing happens, even the **alert** does not get executed.

Please help.

Comment: Remove the script and let the target work. You are not posting from your script

Comment: Also never use "submit" as a form element name

Comment: I added this script because I had the problem above. the script did not change anything.

Comment: 1. Your server wants to post. 2 Your form posts using _blank. So what happens if you remove all submit scripts and just let the form do what it does?

Comment: As I wrote in my question, "Like this, when user hits the button, a new tab opens up where the selected table gets printed (I process it in "tableOutput.php") - this is fine.

But the user needs to return to the first form and select another table, that should be printed in another tab, whereas it gets printed in the same tab as the first one replacing it. In other words, we need to be able to open many new tabs with output."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised the _blank reuses the same new tab

You cannot use window.open to **post** to a new window/tab without a lot of code.

Try this:

```
let cnt = 0;
document.querySelector("[name=frmTableSelect]").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  this.target=`win${cnt++}`;
})
```

Comment: Yes!! It works!!
I do not understand this code, so I'll go learn the documentation now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just change the target in the form to win0, win1, win2 etc

Answer (score -1):

Change .submit to .onclick:

document.getElementById('knopka').onclick = function() {   
    alert('inside javascript'); 
    window.open("tableOutput.php")
  };

Comment: as I wrote above, if I do knopka.onclick , the POST method in "tableOutput.php" does not work

Comment: They already have that code in their example 1